# replace all special characters expect first occurrence of +

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, regex-group, regexp-replace

I want to replace everything other than numeric char from a string, but if + appears at the starting of the string it should be ignored. for example

```
1234++!@#$%^&*()_+=-;',.><:" becomes 1234
+1234 becomes +1234
++++1234 becomes +1234
+1234++!@#$%^&*()_+=-;',.><:" becomes +1234
+1234++!@#$%^&*()_+=-;',.><:" becomes +1234
+1234ABCabc++!@#$%^&*()_+=-;',.><:" becomes +1234
1234ABCabc++!@#$%^&*()_+=-;',.><:" becomes 1234
Aa1234ABCabc++!@#$%^&*()_+=-;',.><:" becomes 1234
a+1234ABCabc++!@#$%^&*()_+=-;',.><:" becomes 1234
1+1234ABCabc++!@#$%^&*()_+=-;',.><:" becomes 11234
```

can you please suggest?

Comment: So you began with `if (str.startsWith('+') { ... }` right?  then what happened?

Comment: so the nearest solution I found is str.replace(/\D/g, '') but this replaces the first + as well. 
I think we can have some regex that can ignore only first occurrence of +

Comment: Many thanks for the help but unfortunately no so a123 should be 123 :(

Comment: Add it to the list of examples, please!  :)

Comment: Did you make any attempts?

Comment: Your last example contradicts your stated objective. Do you want the first number found in a string with optional leading `+` ? Or do you want to extract all digits and retain only the very first `+` preceding the very first digit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

`str.replace(/((?<!^)\D)|(^[^+0-9])/g, '');`

This replaces (with nothing):

- any non-digit that is *not* at the start of the string.
- any non-digit except `+` that *is* at the start of the string.

Comment: many many thanks it works :)
but with a warning 
Unsafe Regular Expressioneslint(security/detect-unsafe-regex)
but I think it's ok to disable it :(
Many many thanks for the help

Comment: in fairness, you could have used your original strategy of `result = str.replace(/\D/g, '')`  But then followed up with `if (str.startsWith('+')) result = '+' + result;` as a fixup.  You were almost there, and there would be no warning.

Comment: yeah, I already have that solution but wanted to get rid of this extra 1 line of if check that can be saved. but I think I have to go back to that solution as our old friend Safari is not able to understand this nice regex and breaks with the error  =>

SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name

Answer (score 0):

This extracts numbers from a string, including an optional leading `+`:

```
var tests = [
  '1234++!@#$%^&*()_+=-;\',.><:"', // becomes 1234
  '+1234', // becomes +1234
  '++++1234', // becomes +1234
  '+1234++!@#$%^&*()_+=-;\',.><:"', // becomes +1234
  '+1234++!@#$%^&*()_+=-;\',.><:"', // becomes +1234
  '+1234ABCabc++!@#$%^&*()_+=-;\',.><:"', // becomes +1234
  '1234ABCabc++!@#$%^&*()_+=-;\',.><:"', // becomes 1234
  'Aa1234ABCabc++!@#$%^&*()_+=-;\',.><:"', // becomes 1234
  'a+1234ABCabc++!@#$%^&*()_+=-;\',.><:"', // becomes 1234
  '1+1234ABCabc++!@#$%^&*()_+=-;\',.><:"' // becomes 11234
];

tests.forEach(str => {
  console.log(str + ' => ' + str.replace(/^.*?(\+?[0-9]+).*$/, '$1'));
});
```

Output:

```
1234++!@#$%^&*()_+=-;',.><:" => 1234
VM1036:2 +1234 => +1234
VM1036:2 ++++1234 => +1234
2VM1036:2 +1234++!@#$%^&*()_+=-;',.><:" => +1234
VM1036:2 +1234ABCabc++!@#$%^&*()_+=-;',.><:" => +1234
VM1036:2 1234ABCabc++!@#$%^&*()_+=-;',.><:" => 1234
VM1036:2 Aa1234ABCabc++!@#$%^&*()_+=-;',.><:" => 1234
VM1036:2 a+1234ABCabc++!@#$%^&*()_+=-;',.><:" => +1234
VM1036:2 1+1234ABCabc++!@#$%^&*()_+=-;',.><:" => 1
```

Your described objective and last example contradict each other. Please be more specific what you need.

Comment: I don't see a contradiction.  I interpret it as:  Any non-digit that is not "a plus at the start of the string" should be removed.